Does Italian law allow a tourist to take a training sword with him?
I'll be going on vacation to Italy by car, and I'd like to take my training sword with me for exercises. Since even a Feder/training sword could easily be used as a weapon, would I risk getting into trouble for it?
In general as I understand it after some research I believe I should be alright if I handle it the same way I would handle it at home in Austria.
Meaning:

no exercising in public while alone (legally no problem, but some people get nervous...), only on fenced in property
while transporting always have it wrapped in a way so I can not be considered "battle ready" (or at least grab it by the dull blade)

I could only find translated materials referencing hunting weapons, knives and weapon like objects in general. A Feder obviously falling into the latter category. What makes me unsure tough is one source explaining that a screwdriver, which would be considered a weapon like object, is ok to have in the trunk but not in the glove box. The relevant difference is not clearly explained, but possibly the readiness of the weapon like object in case of a traffic stop?
Unfortunately if I try to search more specifically for texts talking about Feders in Italy I only end up with results for Italian Feder offers.
So, can anyone give me insights into how reasonable the Austrian approach would be when applied to Italian law?
Or maybe I should try my luck for practical experiences over on travel SE?
Just in case it isn't clear what a Feder looks like: at a glance they can look like actual swords, but have a flat blade with rounded edges, and a widened tip. So anyone actually looking at it (like police called by nervous people confronting a suspect) should quickly realize it is not an actual weapon.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
